# Mysqli select multiple row with same id and sum then return in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with return sum data in MYSQLI and PHP. Here is my database.
[image: Database]

For example,i choose user_id = '0', and i need to sum the number in m_debit and deduct m_credit for user_id = '0' to get the final total. The result should be like this:

The total should be appear in Metallic Point column
[image: The total should be appear in Metallic Point column]

here is my current coding:

```
$get_member = "select sum (m_debit) from transaction_record_tpg where user_id = 0 ";
$run_customer = mysqli_query($conn,$get_member);
$a = mysqli_num_rows($run_customer);
```

can you guys help me to get the result?

[Updated]
Below is my new coding but it doesnt work

```
<?php
$get_member = "SELECT SUM(m_debit) - SUM(m_credit) AS   metallic_point FROM transaction_record_tpg WHERE user_id = 0";
$run_customer = mysqli_query($conn,$get_member);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($run_customer);
?>

<tr>

<td><?php echo $row; ?></td>
<td>2018-10-15 11:03:13</td>
<td>TMA</td>
<td>2018-12-15</td>

</tr><!-- tr Ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum both columns and then subtract one of them to deduct it.

```
SELECT SUM(m_debit) - SUM(m_credit) AS metallic_point
FROM transaction_record_tpg
WHERE user_id = 0
```

There's no point in calling `mysqli_num_rows()`. It will always be 1 for this query. Just fetch the row and use `$row['metallic_point']` as the value.

Comment: Hi, @Barmar, can you help me with my coding? i have try it but it doesnt work. I have updated my coding at the question

Comment: `$row` is an array, you can't echo it. It should be `echo $row['metallic_point'];` like I said in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_member = "SELECT SUM(m_debit) - SUM(m_credit) AS metallic_point FROM transaction_record_tpg WHERE user_id = 0";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $get_member);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $data['metallic_point'];
```

Comment: hi, @catcon, but it keeps saying : Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, may i know how to fix it?

Comment: @louis: does it say boolean given, can you try this "var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));" after mysqli_fetch_array() command to see what is going on.